# Flutter not always running on Windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I’m trying to run a flutter app on Windows for a new project, but I can’t find the option for it in the device selection menu in VS Code, nor is the Windows folder in the project. This happens occasionally with new projects and I don’t know what it is that changes. Can anyone lend me a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to build or run for Windows, or for `flutter create` to create a `windows` folder, you need to meet [the documented tooling requirements](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Desktop-shells#tooling). Currently that means:

- being on master
- having run `flutter config --enable-windows-desktop` at some point

The device won't show up in IDEs unless all those things are true and the project has a `windows` folder.

Comment: So if I have an old project that doesn't have the windows folder, can I not do anything in order to run it on Windows?

Comment: The documentation I linked to answers that question. I highly recommend reading that page if you are experimenting with desktop at this stage.